# DataFrame join optimization - Broadcast Hash Join

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.4

I am trying to effectively join two DataFrames, one of which is large and the second is a bit smaller.

Is there a way to avoid all this shuffling? I cannot set `autoBroadCastJoinThreshold`, because it supports only Integers - and the table I am trying to broadcast is slightly bigger than integer number of bytes.

**Is there a way to force broadcast ignoring this variable?**

Comment: feel like your actual question is "Is there a way to force broadcast ignoring this variable?" It can be controlled through the property I mentioned below..  Since no one addressed, to make it relevant I gave this late answer.Hope that helps!

Comment: Please accept once of the answers as accepted. it will be pointer to others as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 96):

#### Broadcast Hash Joins (similar to ***map side join*** or map-side combine  in Mapreduce) :

In SparkSQL you can see the type of join being performed by calling `queryExecution.executedPlan`. As with core Spark, if one of the tables is much smaller than the other you may want a broadcast hash join. You can hint to Spark SQL that a given DF should be broadcast for join by calling method `broadcast` on the `DataFrame` before joining it

**Example:** 
`largedataframe.join(broadcast(smalldataframe), "key")`

> in DWH terms, where largedataframe  may be like ***fact***
>                       smalldataframe may be like ***dimension***

As described by my fav book (HPS) pls. see below to have better understanding..
[image]

Note : Above `broadcast` is from `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast` not from `SparkContext`

Spark also, automatically uses the `spark.sql.conf.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` to determine if a table should be broadcast.

#### Tip : see DataFrame.explain() method

```
def
explain(): Unit
Prints the physical plan to the console for debugging purposes.
```

---

> #### Is there a way to force broadcast ignoring this variable?

#### `sqlContext.sql("SET spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = -1")`

---

***NOTE :***

> Another similar out of box note w.r.t. Hive (not spark) :  Similar
>   thing can be achieved using hive hint `MAPJOIN` like below...

```
Select /*+ MAPJOIN(b) */ a.key, a.value from a join b on a.key = b.key

hive> set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
hive> set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size=20971520
hive> set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask=true;
hive> set hive.auto.convert.join.use.nonstaged=true;
hive> set hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize = 30000000; // default 25 mb made it as 30mb
```

Further Reading : Please refer my [article on BHJ, SHJ, SMJ](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/spark-sql-3-common-joins-explained-ram-ghadiyaram/)

Comment: Does it make sense to do largeDF.join(broadcast(smallDF), "right_outer") when i want to do smallDF.join(broadcast(largeDF, "left_outer")? since smallDF should be saved in memory instead of largeDF

Comment: Pls. follow [SparkStrategies.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala) here all cases were mentioned. its not single liner to write it here ... changing left_outer to right_outer result will be changed.

Comment: but in normal case Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2, Table2 RIGHT OUTER JOIN Table1 are equal

Answer (score 23):

You can hint for a dataframe to be broadcasted by using `left.join(broadcast(right), ...)`

Comment: What is the right import for this broadcast?  I'm getting that this symbol `broadcast` is not resolvable.

Comment: It is under org.apache.spark.sql.functions, you need spark 1.5.0 or newer

Comment: Any chance to hint broadcast join to a SQL statement?

Comment: You can use the hint in an SQL statement indeed, but not sure how far this works. e.g. I have used it like `left inner join broadcast(right)` not sure if it will work with a subquery

Comment: To broadcast in SparkSQL, you can e.g.:
```val df = broadcast(spark.table("tableA")).createTempView("tableAView")```
```spark.sql("SELECT ... FROM tableAView a JOIN tableB b")```

Comment: HInts are nore supported as of Spark 2.2.0 - see here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16475

Answer (score 7):

Setting `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = -1` will disable broadcast completely. See
[Other Configuration Options in Spark SQL, DataFrames and Datasets Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options).

Answer (score 3):

This is a current limitation of spark, see [SPARK-6235](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235). The 2GB limit also applies for broadcast variables.

Are you sure there is no other good way to do this, e.g. different partitioning?

Otherwise you can hack your way around it by manually creating multiple broadcast variables which are each <2GB.

Comment: I have manage to reduce the size of a smaller table to just a little below the 2 GB, but it seems the broadcast is not happening anyways. (autoBroadcast just wont pick it). It works fine with small tables (100 MB) though.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code works for Broadcast Join in Spark 2.11 version 2.0.0.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast  

val employeesDF = employeesRDD.toDF
val departmentsDF = departmentsRDD.toDF

// materializing the department data
val tmpDepartments = broadcast(departmentsDF.as("departments"))

import context.implicits._

employeesDF.join(broadcast(tmpDepartments), 
   $"depId" === $"id",  // join by employees.depID == departments.id 
   "inner").show()
```

Here is the reference for the above code [Henning Kropp Blog, Broadcast Join with Spark](http://henning.kropponline.de/2016/12/11/broadcast-join-with-spark/)

Answer (score 0):

Using join hints will take precedence over the configuration `autoBroadCastJoinThreshold`, so using a hint will always ignore that threshold.

In addition, when using a join hint the [Adaptive Query Execution](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/aqe.html) (since Spark 3.x) will also not change the strategy given in the hint.

In **Spark SQL** you can apply join hints as shown below:

```sql
SELECT /*+ BROADCAST */ a.id, a.value FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id

SELECT /*+ BROADCASTJOIN */ a.id, a.value FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id

SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN */ a.id, a.value FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```

Note, that the key words BROADCAST, BROADCASTJOIN and MAPJOIN are all aliases as written in the code in [hints.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/hints.scala#L124).