# ERROR Error cleaning broadcast Exception

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, stateful

I get the following error while running my spark streaming application, we have a large application running multiple stateful (with mapWithState) and stateless operations. It's getting difficult to isolate the error since spark itself hangs and the only error we see is in the spark log and not the application log itself.

The error happens only after abount 4-5 mins with a micro-batch interval of 10 seconds.
I am using Spark 1.6.1 on an ubuntu server with Kafka based input and output streams.

**Please note it's not possible for me to provide the smallest possible code to re-create this bug as it does not occur in unit test-cases, and the application itself is very large**

Any direction you can give to solve this issue will be helpful. Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Error inline below:

```
[2017-07-11 16:15:15,338] ERROR Error cleaning broadcast 2211 (org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner)

org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout

        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)

        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)

        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)

        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)

        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)

        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.removeBroadcast(BlockManagerMaster.scala:136)

        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.unpersist(TorrentBroadcast.scala:228)

        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.unbroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:45)

        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.unbroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:77)

        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.doCleanupBroadcast(ContextCleaner.scala:233)

        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ContextCleaner.scala:189)

        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ContextCleaner.scala:180)

        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)

        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:180)

        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1180)

        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:173)

        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$3.run(ContextCleaner.scala:68)

    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]

        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)

        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)

        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)

        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)

        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)

        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
```

Comment: pls. check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40722515/647053) seems like your time out using default 120sec.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram please look at the first error it seems to report error cleaning broadcast... are u saying that itself is happening because of timeout? The workload as such is not changing... its a kafka input stream with a constant input rate...

Comment: Yes.  see [ContextCleaner.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ContextCleaner.scala)->`doCleanupBroadcast` method  error message says that its timeout error due to clean up task. pls increase the timeout period. it should help you.

Comment: was it helpful? were you able to resolve?

Comment: Hi @RamGhadiyaram yes it was helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception message clearly says that its RPCTimeout due to default configuration of 120 seconds and adjust to optimal value as per your work load.
please see [1.6 configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/configuration.html)

your error messages `org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds].`
and 
 `at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)` confirms that.

---

For Better understanding please see the below code from

see [RpcTimeout.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rpc/RpcTimeout.scala)

```
     /**
   * Wait for the completed result and return it. If the result is not available within this
   * timeout, throw a [[RpcTimeoutException]] to indicate which configuration controls the timeout.
   * @param  awaitable  the `Awaitable` to be awaited
   * @throws RpcTimeoutException if after waiting for the specified time `awaitable`
   *         is still not ready
   */
  def awaitResult[T](awaitable: Awaitable[T]): T = {
    try {
      Await.result(awaitable, duration)
    } catch addMessageIfTimeout
  }
}
```

- Also see [my answer in another context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40722515/647053)