# Persisting a data frame in pyspark2 does not work when a storage level is specified. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to persist two very large data frames before performing a join to workaround the "java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out..." issue (ref: [Why does join fail with "java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300 seconds]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123846/why-does-join-fail-with-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-futures-timed-ou)).

Persist(), alone, works but when I try to specify a storage level, I receive name errors.

I've tried the following:

```
df.persist(pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY) 
NameError: name 'MEMORY_ONLY' is not defined

df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY) 
NameError: name 'StorageLevel' is not defined

import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel 
ImportError: No module named org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to import the appropriate package:-

```
from pyspark import StorageLevel
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
from pyspark.storagelevel import StorageLevel

df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the pyspark package

```
import pyspark
```