# Databricks: Structured Stream fails with TimeoutException

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, streaming

I want to create a structured stream in databricks with a kafka source.
I followed the instructions as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html). My script seems to start, however it fails with the first element of the stream. The stream itsellf works fine and produces results and works (in databricks) when I use `confluent_kafka`, thus there seems to be a different issue I am missing:

After the initial stream is processed, the script times out:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Stream Execution thread for stream [id = 80afdeed-9266-4db4-85fa-66ccf261aee4, 
runId = b564c626-9c74-42a8-8066-f1f16c7ab53d] failed to stop within 36000 milliseconds (specified by spark.sql.streaming.stopTimeout). See the cause on what was being executed in the streaming query thread.`
```

WHAT I TRIED: looking at SO and finding [this](http://thishttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123846/why-does-join-fail-with-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-futures-timed-ou) answer, to which I included
`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.stopTimeout",  36000)`
into my setup - which changed nothing.

Any input is highly appreciated!

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Define a data schema
schema = StructType() \
           .add('PARAMETERS_TEXTVALUES_070_VALUES', StringType())\
           .add('ID', StringType())\
           .add('PARAMETERS_TEXTVALUES_001_VALUES', StringType())\
           .add('TIMESTAMP', TimestampType())


df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("host", "stream.xxx.com") \
    .option("port", 12345)\
    .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'stream.xxx.com:12345') \
    .option('subscribe', 'stream_test.json') \
    .option("startingOffset", "earliest") \
    .load()

df_word = df.select(F.col('key').cast('string'),
                    F.from_json(F.col('value').cast('string'), schema).alias("parsed_value"))
  

df_word \
      .writeStream \
      .format("parquet") \
      .option("path", "dbfs:/mnt/streamfolder/stream/") \
      .option("checkpointLocation", "dbfs:/mnt/streamfolder/check/") \
      .outputMode("append") \
      .start()
```

my stream output data looks like this:

```
"PARAMETERS_TEXTVALUES_070_VALUES":'something'
"ID":"47575963333908"
"PARAMETERS_TEXTVALUES_001_VALUES":12345
"TIMESTAMP": "2020-10-22T15:06:42.507+02:00"
```

Furthermore, `stream` and `check` folders are filled with 0-b files, except for `metadata`, which includes the ìd from the error above.

Thanks and stay safe.

Comment: how much data is in the Kafka topic? did you also call `awaitTermination` at the end of your code? (it is not visible in your question)

Comment: hi @mike - as I showed, there are 4 columns with some strings in the kafka topic. I tried `awaitTermination` - no change, therefore I omitted it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I checked the driver logs and discovered this exception in the stacktrace:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to store executor broadcast spark_join_relation_3540_1455983219 (size = Some(67371008)) in BlockManager with storageLevel=StorageLevel(memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
```

Based on [this recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1179129/job-aborted-due-to-stage-failure-task-0-in-stage-1) I raised Driver memory (16gb to 32gb in my case) and it solved the issue.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74139881/7680816) on StackOverflow explains why it works.