# Why BroadcastExchange needs more driver memory?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When broadcasting, Spark can fail with the error `org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors#notEnoughMemoryToBuildAndBroadcastTableError` (Spark 3.2.1):

[image]

Why BroadcastExchange needs more driver memory? Isn't broadcast sending data to all drivers? Why driver memory is a bottleneck?

Thanks.

Comment: yes but the broadcasted variable is sent from the driver to all workers. it should be serialized on driver first.

Comment: even in a broadcast join? makes little sense to me to bring the whole dataframe to the driver..

Comment: only driver communicate to all workers, a worker cannot sent anything to another worker imo. So anything shared to all workers go through the driver.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the case until executor side broadcast joins are implemented (see SPARK-17556)

Comment: ahh ohhh.. that's so eye-opening! Thank you all.

Comment: Btw, I can recommend this talk on the topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9aY7KkTLTw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately executor side broadcast joins are not yet supported in Spark (see [SPARK-17556](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17556)). Currently all data of the broadcasted dataset is collected in the driver first to build an in-memory hash table which is then distributed to workers. This can result in high memory pressure on the driver.