# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException error in spark Databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rabbitmq, databricks, azure-databricks

Im using the below custom receiver to consume data from Rabbitmq in Spark-Scala. Below is my code.

```
def onStart() {
    // Start the thread that receives data over a connection
    new Thread("Socket Receiver") {
      override def run() { receive() }
    }.start()
  }

  def onStop() {
    // There is nothing much to do as the thread calling receive()
    // is designed to stop by itself isStopped() returns false
  }

  /** Create a socket connection and receive data until receiver is stopped */
   def receive() {
    var socket: Socket = null
    var userInput: String = null
    try {
     
     var batchInterval = Seconds(20)
              var ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, batchInterval)
      val host = ""
                val port = ""
                val queueName = ""
                val vHost = ""
                val userName = ""
                val password = ""
val maxMessagesPerPartition = "1000"
                val maxReceiveTime = "0.9"
      
        val receiverStream = RabbitMQUtils.createStream(ssc, Map(
      "host" -> "host",
      "port" -> "port",
      "queueName" -> "queueName",
      "vHost" -> "vHost",
      "userName" -> "userName",
      "password" -> "password", 
"maxMessagesPerPartition" -> "maxMessagesPerPartition",
 "maxReceiveTime"   -> "maxReceiveTime"
          ))
     
       val lines = ssc.receiverStream(new CustomReceiver(host, port.toInt))
    lines.foreachRDD(rdd =>{ val df=rdd.toDF
                        
 
  import sqlContext.implicits._
 
  df.write.format("parquet").mode("append").save("path")
  
})

      lines.print()
      ssc.start() 
      ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Im getting the below time out error.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.runInNewThreadWithTimeout(ThreadUtils.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.runInNewThread(ThreadUtils.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:577)
    at lined28d5369d60244b0a66d1d87a30c93a027.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1212830188116081:87)
    at lined28d5369d60244b0a66d1d87a30c93a027.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1212830188116081:188)
    at lined28d5369d60244b0a66d1d87a30c93a027.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1212830188116081:190)
    at lined28d5369d60244b0a66d1d87a30c93a027.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1212830188116081:192)
    at lined28d5369d60244b0a66d1d87a30c93a027.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1212830188116081:194)
    at lined28d5369d60244b0a66d1d87a30c93a027.$read$$iw.<init>(command-1212830188116081:196)
    at lined28d5369d60244b0a66d1d87a30c93a027.$read.<init>(command-1212830188116081:198)
    at lined28d5369d60244b0a66d1d87a30c93a027.$read$.<init>(command-1212830188116081:202)
    at lined28d5369d60244b0a66d1d87a30c93a027.$read$.<clinit>(command-1212830188116081)
    at lined28d5369d60244b0a66d1d87a30c93a027.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at lined28d5369d60244b0a66d1d87a30c93a027.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at lined28d5369d60244b0a66d1d87a30c93a027.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1021)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:574)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
```

Does this error means that the current spark cluster configuration is not able to handle the incoming message load. Is it related to any memory issue.Could someone please assist.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to Increase `spark.driver.memory` to higher value.

Also try to increase the `broadcastTimeout`.

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123846/why-does-join-fail-with-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-futures-timed-ou) by T. Gawęda