# What is the maximum size for a broadcast object in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, broadcast

When using Dataframe [broadcast](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#broadcast(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset)) function or the SparkContext [broadcast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#broadcast(T,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) functions, what is the maximum object size that can be dispatched to all executors?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a 2G limit but not sure it's wise to broadcast that much data.

Comment: @vanza: I am aware of [Address various 2G limits](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235) but I m not sure that this is applicable [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/broadcast/TorrentBroadcast.scala) as well. we have `rdd.cache()` to cache `RDD` in memory but there also they have not mentioned any limit for this in doc.  "not sure  it's wise to broadcast that much data"... I agree with you on this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### [`broadcast` function :](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#broadcast(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset))

Default is 10mb but we have used till 300 mb which is controlled by [spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435263/dataframe-join-optimization-broadcast-hash-join/39404486#39404486).

AFAIK, It all  depends on memory available. so there is no definite answer for this. what I would say is,  it should be less than large dataframe and you can estimate large or small dataframe size like below...

```
import org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator

logInfo(SizeEstimator.estimate(yourlargeorsmalldataframehere))
```

based on this you can pass `broadcast` hint to framework.

Also have a look at 
 scala doc from 
[sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala)

which says....

> - Broadcast: if one side of the join has an estimated physical size that is smaller than the      user-configurable
>     [[SQLConf.AUTO_BROADCASTJOIN_THRESHOLD]] threshold  or if that
>     side has an explicit broadcast hint (e.g. the user applied the
>     [[org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast()]] function to a
>     DataFrame), then that side   of the join will be broadcasted
>     and the other side will be streamed, with no shuffling
>     performed. If both sides are below the
>     threshold, broadcast the smaller side. If neither is smaller, BHJ is  not used.
> - Shuffle hash join: if the average size of a single
>     partition is small enough to build a hash    table.
> - Sort merge: if the matching join keys are sortable.
> - If there is no joining keys, Join implementations are chosen with the following precedence:
>
>   - BroadcastNestedLoopJoin: if one side of the join could be broadcasted
>   - CartesianProduct: for Inner join
>   - BroadcastNestedLoopJoin

Also have a look at [other-configuration-options](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options)

#### `SparkContext.broadcast` (TorrentBroadcast ) :

broadcast shared variable  also has a property  `spark.broadcast.blockSize=4M` 
AFAIK there is no hard core limitation I have seen for this as well...

for Further information pls. see [TorrentBroadcast.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/broadcast/TorrentBroadcast.scala)

---

#### EDIT :

However you can have look at 2GB issue Even though that was officially not declared in docs (I was not able to see anything of this kind in docs).
pls look at [SPARK-6235 which is "IN PROGRESS" state](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235) & [SPARK-6235_Design_V0.02.pdf](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12827296/SPARK-6235_Design_V0.02.pdf) .

Comment: The `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` appears as though it is the threshold for an automatic broadcast. I'm asking about the maximum size for an explicit broadcast - similar but different.

Comment: BHJ: Broadcast Hash Join

Answer (score 20):

As of Spark 2.4, there's an upper limit of 8 GB. [Source Code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/79c66894296840cc4a5bf6c8718ecfd2b08bcca8/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/BroadcastExchangeExec.scala#L104)

Update :
The 8GB limit is still valid for Spark 3.2.1 [Source Code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b8d3da16b1bdde60b50e364a4ff98cb6bf8ccd7e/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/BroadcastExchangeExec.scala#L225)

Update:
Still valid for Spark 3.4 [Source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e17d8ecabcad6e84428752b977120ff355a4007a/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/BroadcastExchangeExec.scala#L226)

Comment: When we are talking about 8GB, we are talking about 8GB for every single object to be broadcasted and unlimited number of broadcasted objects in case of available memory in Spark cluster or about 8GB as a total memory which can be allocated for all broadcasted objects?

Comment: The limits are per object and not an overall limit.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned above, the upper limit is 8GB. But when you have several files you want to broadcast, spark push all the data files to driver. The driver join those files & push to to executor nodes. In this process, if the driver's available memory is less than combined broadcast file, you will end up with out of memory error.