# Processing Hive Lookup tables in Spark vs Spark Broadcast variables

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, lookup

i have a two data sets names `dataset1` and `dataset2` and `dataset1` is like

```
empid  empame
101    john
102    kevin
```

and `dataset2` is like

```
empid  empmarks  empaddress
101      75        LA
102      69        NY
```

The `dataset2` will be very huge and i need to process some operations on these two datasets and need to get results from above two `datasets`.
As of my knowledge, now i have two options to process these datasets:

1.Store **dataset1**(which is lesser in size) as **hive lookup table** and have to process them through **Spark**

2.By using **Spark Broadcast Variables** we can process these `dataset`.

Anyone please suggest me which one is the better option.

Comment: right now  these datasets present in hive or text file ?

Comment: present in text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be better option than those 2 options mentioned.

since you have common key you can do inner join.

```
dataset2.join(dataset1, Seq("empid"), "inner").show()
```

you can use `broadcast` function/hint like this as well. which means you are telling framework that small dataframe i.e dataset1 should be broadcasted to every executor.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
dataset2.join(broadcast(dataset1), Seq("empid"), "inner").show()
```

Also Look at for more details..

- [DataFrame join optimization - Broadcast Hash Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435263/dataframe-join-optimization-broadcast-hash-join/39404486#39404486) how broadcast joins will work.
- [What-is-the-maximum-size-for-a-broadcast-object-in-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41046320/647053)

Comment: added import  for `broadcast` function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137198/perform-rdd-operations-on-dataframes look at this

Comment: @ Ram Ghadiyaram , can you please share your email id or skype id. So that i can explain my problem clearly