# perform RDD operations on DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataset of 10 fields. I need to perform RDD operations on these DataFrame. Is it possible to perform RDD operations like `map`, `flatMap`, etc..

here is my sample code:

```
df.select("COUNTY","VEHICLES").show();
```

this is my `dataframe` and i need to convert this `dataframe` to `RDD` and operate some RDD operations on this new RDD.

Here is code how i am converted dataframe to RDD

```
 RDD<Row> java = df.select("COUNTY","VEHICLES").rdd();
```

after converting to RDD, i am not able to see the RDD results, i tried

```
java.collect();
java.take(10);
java.foreach();
```

In all above cases i failed to get results.

please help me out.

Comment: what about `df.select("COUNTY","VEHICLES").rdd.collect()` ?

Comment: Just as a side note, in many cases you can perform many of these actions much more easily by using the dataframe `withColumn` method instead of using the `map`/`flatMap` overcomplicated syntax. Maybe you should show an example of what you actually trying to do and provide an actual data set.

Comment: @mtoto won't that put everything into a single node?

Comment: It will, it's just to illustrate that you don't need brackets to use the `rdd` method.

Comment: df.select("COUNTY","VEHICLES").rdd.collect() if i print like this its prints nothing.

Comment: first do df.select("COUNTY","VEHICLES").show to ensure that results are there in your dataframe then convert to RDD

Comment: df.select("COUNTY","VEHICLES").show() returning results ?

Comment: DataFrame df3 = df1.select("COUNTY");
    List<Row>nameRDD = df3.collectAsList();
    JavaSparkContext sc= new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<Row> lis = sc.parallelize(nameRDD);
    System.out.println(lis.take(5)); this is working

Answer (score 0):

```
val myRdd : RDD[String] = ds.rdd
```

Check the Spark Api documentation [Dataset to RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@javaRDD:org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[T]).`lazy val
rdd: RDD[T]`

In your case create the Dataframe with selected of record by performing select after that call `.rdd` it wil convert it to RDD

Comment: In that case first ground level needs to be checked whether Dataframe has the data. If yes then after querying on dataframe and trying to show it if its coming then it needs to be check why its not coming to RDD. This is more towards debugging .

Answer (score 0):

**For Spark 1.6 :**

You won't be able to see the result's as when you are converting a `Dataframe` to a RDD what it does is it converts it into `RDD[Row]`

And hence when you try any of these :

```
java.collect();
java.take(10);
java.foreach();
```

It would be resulting in `Array[Row]` and you are not able to get the results.

**Solution:**

You can convert the Row to respective values and get the `RDD` out of it like here :

```
val newDF=df.select("COUNTY","VEHICLES")
val resultantRDD=newDF.rdd.map{row=>
val county=row.getAs[String]("COUNTY")
val vehicles=row.getAs[String]("VEHICLES")
(county,vehicles)
}
```

And now you can apply the `foreach` and `collect` function to get the value.

**P.S.:** The code is written in Scala , but you can get the essence of what I am trying to do !

Answer (score 0):

Since spark 2.0 you can convert DataFrame to DataSet using `toDS` function in order to use RDD operations.
Recommend this great [article](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-dataset-operators.html) about mastering spark 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try persisting the rdd before reading the data from rdd.

```
val finalRdd = mbnfinal.rdd
finalRdd.cache()
finalRdd.count()
```