# How to fix broadcast join in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, join, broadcast

Spark BroadcastJoin hint not broadcasting as expected (Spark 2.3)

I have 2 Dataframes, let's say a & b. Dataframe a is fairly small with 50000 rows, about 940 K size. Dataframe b is large with 12TB of data.
I am joining like:

```
Broadcast(a).join(b, $"a.id" === $"b.id", "left")
```

but query plan says `SortMergeJoin [id#163], [id#187], LeftOuter`
I was hoping to see `BroadcastHashJoin`

I tried other options & observed that:

```
b.join(Broadcast(a), $"a.id" === $"b.id", "left")
```

gives me `BroadcastHashJoin [id#163], [id#187], LeftOuter, BuildRight`
This was just an experiment. I can't use this because I need "a left join b".

I tried `b.join(Broadcast(a), $"a.id" === $"b.id", "right")` but this again gives me SortMergeJoin.

Memory is not an issue. I don't see any spills. The driver has 16GB too.

Any idea, why Spark might not Broadcast in spite of smaller dataset and an explicit hint?

Comment: It is more likely that your small dataframe is larger than the setting `spark.broadcast.blockSize` which is 10M by default. First make an estimation of the size of the dataframe you want to broadcast then try to change the broadcast size controlled by `spark.broadcast.blockSize` as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045917/what-is-the-maximum-size-for-a-broadcast-object-in-spark