# Using Pandas UDF with Large Broadcast object

Tags: serialization, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to use Pandas UDF GROUPEDMAP to do some processing. The code is below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType, spark_partition_id

models_broadcast = self.spark_session.sparkContext.broadcast(models)

@pandas_udf("id string, score string",
                    PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def _segment_partition_score(segment_partition_pd):

  my_models = models_broadcast.value # comment this line, the code ran run through

  segment_partition_pd["score"] = "aaa"

  segment_score_pd = segment_partition_pd[['id', 'score']]

  return segment_score_pd


model_score = my_data_df.withColumn("pid", spark_partition_id()).groupby('pid').apply(_segment_partition_score)

model_score.show(100)
```

Here is the error message. It simply states " java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

```
y4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1525.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 31.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 31.0 (TID 2466, 10.139.64.43, executor 10): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:494)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:543)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2362)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2350)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2582)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2529)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2517)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollectResult(limit.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectResult(Dataset.scala:2905)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3517)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2634)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2634)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$54.apply(Dataset.scala:3501)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$54.apply(Dataset.scala:3496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:835)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2634)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2848)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:316)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:494)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:543)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

1. The broadcast object is a pickle object which is around ~100 MB. It is a trained ski-learn machine learning model.
2. But you may find, in the UDF _segment_partition_score, I actually didn't use this broadcast object. I just want to get it at the UDF, for debugging purpose. Even this, the pyspark program will crash.
3. If I don't receive this broadcast object in the Pandas UDF, the program can run through, and generate result.
4. The dataframe "my_data_df" is very small (700 MB in Parquet) . I am sure given the existing cluster size (64GB) * 20 workers, it should be no problem to deal with it.

I highly suspect that it is the problem of serialization for the broadcast object, either size or type of serializer. But I have no idea what should I tune.

Could anyone point me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a limit to the size of a broadcast variable. Seems to be 10mb https://stackoverflow.com/a/41046320/2596363 but can be increased.