# Broadcast dataframe are forming sort merge join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have broadcasted a table which is less than 2GB, the explain plan anyway shows a sort merge join on the table.
Cab auto-broadcast turn off for some reason?

Comment: this exceeds the upper limit of 10MB which is the default value, please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045917/what-is-the-maximum-size-for-a-broadcast-object-in-spark

Comment: if your cluster have huge resources like RAM and disk and only one application run at a time. then tune spark spark.sql.autobroadcastjointhreshold value to 2GB ... i would personally won't brodcast such huge data ... it has huge overhead and decrease task performance overall.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs! The issue was caused by an empty table.