# Can you do a broadcast join with SparkR?

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I'm trying to join a large dataframe to a smaller dataframe and I saw that broadcast join is an efficient way to do that, according to this [post](http://henning.kropponline.de/2016/12/11/broadcast-join-with-spark/).

However I couldn't find the broadcast function in the SparkR [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html).

So I'm wondering if you can do a broadcast join with SparkR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spark 2.3:**
There will be `broadcast` function created in this pull request: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17965/files

**Spark 2.2:**

You can provide custom hint to query:

```
head(join(df, hint(avg_mpg, "broadcast"), df$cyl == avg_mpg$cyl))
```

Reference: this code: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/R/pkg/R/DataFrame.R#L3740

Broadcast function in Java, Scala and Python API is also a wrapper for adding broadcast hint. Hint means that optimizer gets additional information: this DataFrame is small, I - user - guarantee this, you should do broadcast before joining with other DataFrames.

**Side note:**
Spark sometimes do automatically performs Broadcast Join. You can manipulate configuration of automatic Broadcast Joins by setting:

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = -1")
```

Here, -1 means that no DataFrame will be broadcasted to use Broadcast Join. You can read about this topic more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435263/dataframe-join-optimization-broadcast-hash-join)

Comment: What's with the "hint" ?

Comment: hint is function, available from Spark 2.2