# Join relatively small table with large table in Spark 2.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am currently working on updating a table based on its existence on another table:

Ex:

Dataset A (relatively small, 300k of rows): **DepartmentId, EmployeeId, Salary, Error**

Dataset B (relatively huge, millions of rows): **DepartmentId, EmployeeId, Salary**

The logic is:
1. If A's (DepartmentId, EmployeeId) pair exists in B, then update A's salary with B's salary
2. Otherwise, write a message to A's error field

The solution I have now is doing a left outer join on A with B. Is there any other better practices for this type of problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

For better performance, you can use broadcast hash join as mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435263/dataframe-join-optimization-broadcast-hash-join) by @Ram Ghadiyaram

The broadcasted dataframe will be distributed in all the partition which increases the performance in joining.

[DataFrame join optimization - Broadcast Hash Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435263/dataframe-join-optimization-broadcast-hash-join)

Hope this helps!

Comment: does broadcast hash join work for smallTable.join(bigTable) tho?

Comment: Yes it works for broadcasr(smallTable).join(bigTable) as well