# Spark: Faster way to join two dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframe `df1` and `ip2Country`. 
`df1` contains the IP addresses and I am trying to map the ip addresses into *geolocation* information like *longitude* and *latitude* which are columns in `ip2Country`.

I am running it as a Spark-submit job, but the operations took a very long time even though `df1` only has less than 2500 lines.

My code:

```
val agg =df1.join(ip2Country, ip2Country("network_start_int")=df1("sint")
, "inner")
.select($"src_ip"
,$"country_name".alias("scountry")
,$"iso_3".alias("scode")
,$"longitude".alias("slong")
,$"latitude".alias("slat")
,$"dst_ip",$"dint",$"count")
.filter($"slong".isNotNull)

val agg1 =agg.join(ip2Country, ip2Country("network_start_int")=agg("dint")
, "inner")
.select($"src_ip",$"scountry"
,$"scode",$"slong"
,$"slat",$"dst_ip"
,$"country_name".alias("dcountry")
,$"iso_3".alias("dcode")
,$"longitude".alias("dlong")
,$"latitude".alias("dlat"),$"count")
.filter($"dlong".isNotNull)
```

Is there any other way to join the two table? Or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: which one is taking more time agg or agg1?

Comment: actually both are taking a long time. When I printed the sys.time, then agg1 is taking a longer time

Comment: Largedf.join(broadcast(smalldf)) will work where broadcast is hint to framework

Comment: so is like ip2Country.join(broadcast(df1),...) ?

Comment: Yes that should work

Comment: yes see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39404486/647053) it will clearly explain why it works better. more details were explained in nice way. it you like that please vote-up. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a big dataframe which needs to be joined with a small one - Broadcast joins are very effective. Read here: [Broadcast Joins (aka Map-Side Joins)](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins-broadcast.html)

```
bigdf.join(broadcast(smalldf))
```