# access scala map from dataframe without using UDFs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, user-defined-functions

I have a Spark (version 1.6) `Dataframe`, and I would like to add a column with a value contained in a Scala Map, this is my simplified code:

```
val map = Map("VAL1" -> 1, "VAL2" -> 2)
val df2 = df.withColumn("newVal", map(col("key")))
```

This code doesn't work and obviously I receive the following error, because the map expecting a String value, while receiving a column:

```
found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
required: String
```

The only way I could do that is using an UDF:

```
val map = Map("VAL1" -> 1, "VAL2" -> 2)
val myUdf = udf{ value:String => map(value)}
val df2 = df.withColumn("newVal", myUdf($"key"))
```

I want avoid the use of UDFs if possible.

Are there any other solutions available using just the DataFrame API (I  would like also to avoid transforming it to RDD)?

Comment: You can work with `DataSet` or convert to RDD, get the map value, and convert to dataframe back again.

Comment: I think I can't because I'm using Spark 1.6 and DataSet were in a Beta version. Could you provide an example using just the API DataFrame if possible? I update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the Map to a Dataframe and use a JOIN between this and your existing dataframe. Since the Map dataframe would be very small, it should be a Broadcast Join and avoid the need for a shuffle phase.

Letting Spark know to use a broadcast join is described in this answer: [DataFrame join optimization - Broadcast Hash Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435263/dataframe-join-optimization-broadcast-hash-join)

Comment: Thanks @mattinbits, this did the trick. I refactored my code creating a new `DataFrame` and joining it with the existing one

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** Just use `udf`.

With the version you use (Spark 1.6 according to your comment) there is no solution which doesn't require `udf` or `map` over `RDD` / `Dataset`.

In later versions you can:

- use `map` functions (2.0 or later) to create literal `MapType` column

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

  val map = functions.map(
     Map("VAL1" -> 1, "VAL2" -> 2)
       .flatMap { case (k, v) =>  Seq(k, v) } .map(lit) .toSeq: _*
  )
  map($"key")
  ```
- `typedLit` (2.2 or later) to create literal `MapType` column.

  ```
  val map = functions.typedLit(Map("VAL1" -> 1, "VAL2" -> 2))
  map($"key")
  ```

and use these directly.

Reference [How to add a constant column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32788322)