# Apache Spark column with collected info vs rows union

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame:

```
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|  name|             email|         phone|      country|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|  Mike|  mike@example.com|+91-9999999999|        Italy|
|  Alex|  alex@example.com|+91-9999999998|       France|
|  John|  john@example.com| +1-1111111111|United States|
|Donald|donald@example.com| +1-2222222222|United States|
|   Dan|   dan@example.com|+91-9999444999|       Poland|
| Scott| scott@example.com|+91-9111999998|        Spain|
|   Rob|   rob@example.com|+91-9114444998|        Italy|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

after applying the following transformation:

```
val tags = Map(
  "big" -> "country IN (FROM big_countries)",
  "medium" -> "country IN (FROM medium_countries)",
  // a few thousands of other tag keys and conditions with any possible SQL statements allowed in SQL WHERE clause(users create them on the application UI)
  "sometag" -> "name = 'Donald' AND email = 'donald@example.com' AND phone = '+1-2222222222'")

def buildTagQuery(tag: String, tagCondition: String, table: String): String = {
    f"FROM $table WHERE $tagCondition"
}

val userTags = tags.map {
  case (tag, tagCondition) => {
    spark.sql(buildTagQuery(tag, tagCondition, "users"))
      .withColumn("tag", lit(tag).cast(StringType))
  }
}

val unionDf = userTags.foldLeft(userTags.head) {
  case (acc, df) => acc.union(df)
}
```

I receive the following DataFrame:

```
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-------+
|  name|             email|         phone|      country|    tag|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-------+
|  Mike|  mike@example.com|+91-9999999999|        Italy|    big|
|  Alex|  alex@example.com|+91-9999999998|       France|    big|
|  John|  john@example.com| +1-1111111111|United States|    big|
|Donald|donald@example.com| +1-2222222222|United States|    big|
| Scott| scott@example.com|+91-9111999998|        Spain|    big|
|   Rob|   rob@example.com|+91-9114444998|        Italy|    big|
|  Mike|  mike@example.com|+91-9999999999|        Italy|    big|
|  Alex|  alex@example.com|+91-9999999998|       France|    big|
|  John|  john@example.com| +1-1111111111|United States|    big|
|Donald|donald@example.com| +1-2222222222|United States|    big|
| Scott| scott@example.com|+91-9111999998|        Spain|    big|
|   Rob|   rob@example.com|+91-9114444998|        Italy|    big|
|   Dan|   dan@example.com|+91-9999444999|       Poland| medium|
| Scott| scott@example.com|+91-9111999998|        Spain| medium|
|Donald|donald@example.com| +1-2222222222|United States|sometag|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-------+
```

which duplicates each original DataFrame record with additional information in tag column but I need something like this(not duplicated records from the original DataFrame and collection of tags in the `tag` column):

```
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
|  name|             email|         phone|      country|           tag|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
|  Mike|  mike@example.com|+91-9999999999|        Italy|         [big]|
|  Alex|  alex@example.com|+91-9999999998|       France|         [big]|
|  John|  john@example.com| +1-1111111111|United States|         [big]|
|Donald|donald@example.com| +1-2222222222|United States| [big,sometag]|
|   Dan|   dan@example.com|+91-9999444999|       Poland|      [medium]|
| Scott| scott@example.com|+91-9111999998|        Spain|  [big,medium]|
|   Rob|   rob@example.com|+91-9114444998|        Italy|         [big]|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Right now I don't know how to change my transformation in order to receive such a structure with the `tag` column like `ArrayType` without original row duplication.

Comment: Can you please post the code `buildTagQuery(tag, tagCondition, "tagged_users")`, maybe we can create an `UDF` that produces the `tag` column by which we can avoid union, map and foldLeft on dataframes. Or add all the columns in the `sql` query so that union can be avioded.

Comment: @PavithranRamachandran please see the updated question. I have added the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible method without changing too much of your logic.

First you will have to assign a unique id to the users table. As shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val userstable = spark.sql("select * from users")

val userswithId = userstable.withColumn("UniqueID", monotonically_increasing_id())

userswithId.createOrReplaceTempView("users")
```

Now your `tags` and `userTags` remains same as above.

```
val tags = Map(
  "big" -> "country IN (FROM big_countries)",
  "medium" -> "country IN (FROM medium_countries)",
  // a few thousands of other tag keys and conditions with any possible SQL statements allowed in SQL WHERE clause(users create them on the application UI)
  "sometag" -> "name = 'Donald' AND email = 'donald@example.com' AND phone = '+1-2222222222'")

def buildTagQuery(tag: String, tagCondition: String, table: String): String = {
  f"FROM $table WHERE $tagCondition"
}
```

Here we are only selecting on the `UniqueID` and `tag` columns.

```
val userTags = tags.map {
  case (tag, tagCondition) => {
    spark.sql(buildTagQuery(tag, tagCondition, "users"))
      .withColumn("tag", lit(tag).cast(StringType)).select("UniqueID", "tag")
  }
}
```

This is very important. There was a subtle bug in your original code using foldLeft. The head of the list was folded twice in your case. What I have done here is selected the head into a separate variable and then dropped it from `userTags`. The folding logic is same as before. But in this case we are not folding the head element twice.

```
val headhere = userTags.head
val userResults  = userTags.drop(1)
val unionDf2 = userResults.foldLeft(headhere) {
  case (acc, df) => acc.union(df)
}
```

Now we are grouping-by the `UniqueID` column while aggregating the `tags` into its own list.

```
val unionDf3 = unionDf2.groupBy("UniqueID").agg(collect_list("tag"))

println("Printing the unionDf3 result")
unionDf3.show(25)
```

Finally we are joining your `users` table with UniqueID which we assigned earlier (i.e. table `userswithId`) with previous dataframe to get the final result.

```
val finalResult = userswithId.join(unionDf3,"UniqueID")

println("Printing the final result")
finalResult.show(25)
```

Final result is as below :

```
+--------+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+
|UniqueID|  name|             email|         phone|      country|collect_list(tag)|
+--------+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+
|       0|  Alex|  alex@example.com|+91-9999999998|       France|            [big]|
|       1|  John|  john@example.com| +1-1111111111|United States|            [big]|
|       2|Donald|donald@example.com| +1-2222222222|United States|   [big, sometag]|
|       4| Scott| scott@example.com|+91-9111999998|        Spain|    [big, medium]|
+--------+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please compare from the performance point of view - your solution and `groupBy` by all columns, something like that : `val taggedUsers = unionDf.groupBy(unionDf.columns.diff(Seq("tag")).map(col): _*).agg(collect_set("tag").alias("tags"))` ?

Comment: I think you will have to benchmark it. In my solution, there is uniqueId generation, groupBy on a smaller table on a single column which is numeric and join to get the final result. In your case, you are grouping by all the columns except `tag` column and then aggregating the tags list. I can't really tell which solution would be faster in practice.

Comment: Thanks, I feel simple join(your solution) will work much faster. Thanks again!

Comment: @alexanoid : In case the dataframe `unionDf3` is small enough, you can use a broadcast join to make it slightly faster. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435263/dataframe-join-optimization-broadcast-hash-join