# Spark SQL (Java) - Inexpensive way to join X number of files?

Tags: java, apache-spark, join

I am currently working on a project where I am reading 19 different parquet files and joining on an ID. Some of these files have multiple rows per consumer, some have none.

I have a key file which has 1 column that I join on and another (userName) that I need, and I need all the columns of the other files.

I create a different reader for each parquet file which reads the file and converts it into a spark dataset with a structure like this:

```
GenericStructure1 record;
int id;
```

I then join all of these created datasets like this (imagine all 19):

```
keyDataset.join(dataSet1, dataSet1.col("id").equalTo(keyDataset.col("id")), "left_outer")
.join(dataSet19, dataSet19.col("id").equalTo(keyDataset.col("id")), "left_outer")
.groupBy(keyDataset.col("id"), keyDataset.col("userName"))
.agg(
    collect_set(dataSet1.col("record")).as("set1"),
    collect_set(dataSet19.col("record")).as("set19")
.select(
    keyDataset.col("id"),
    keyDataset.col("userName"),
    col("set1"),
    col("set19")
)
.as(Encoders.bean(Set.class));
```

where Set.class looks something like this:

```
public class Set implements Serializable {
    long id;
    String userName;
    List<GenericStructure1> set1;
    List<GenericStructure19> set19;
}
```

This works fine for 100 records, but when I try to ramp up to one part of a 5mm parquet file (something like 75K records), it churns and burns through memory until ultimately it runs out. In production I need for this to be able to run on millions, so the fact that it chokes on 75K is a real problem. The only thing is, I don't see a straightforward way to optimize this so it can handle that kind of workload. Does anybody know of an inexpensive way to join a large amount of data like shown above?

Comment: Well, joining 19 datasets can become very expensive... when you join 2 75k record tables you could get 75ˆ2 = 5625000000 records, so 19 would be 75ˆ19  could become 4.23e92... That could be a lot of records, even for Spark... Maybe you can union them? What is your record looking like?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did try doing a union, but it complained about the type of my GenericStructure column.  I seem to remember a way to transpose the data from rows to column.  If I was able to do that then all of the columns would be long and maybe it would stop complaining.  I will update when I know.

Comment: Scratch that.  I was thinking of joinWith and that's not what it does.  I did figure out a solution though, thanks jgp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work. In the question, I mention a keyDataset, which has all of the keys possible in all of the different datasets. Instead of trying to join that against all of the other files right out of the gate, I instead broadcast the keyDataset and join against that after creating a generic dataframe for each dataset.

```
Dataset<Row> set1RowDataset = set1Dataset
        .groupBy(keyDataset.col(joinColumn))
        .agg(collect_set(set1Dataset.col("record")).as("set1s"))
        .select(
                keyDataset.col("id"),
                col("set1"));
```

Once I create 19 of those, I then join the generic datasets in their own join like so:

```
broadcast(set1RowDataset)
        .join(set2RowDataset, "id")
        .join(set3RowDataset, "id")
        .join(set4RowDataset, "id")
        .join(set19RowDataset, "id")
        .as(Encoders.bean(Set.class));
```

Performance-wise, I'm not sure how much of a hit I'm taking by doing the groupBy separately from the join, but my memory remains intact and Spark no longer spills so badly to disk during the shuffle.  I was able to run this on one part locally which was failing before as I mentioned above.  I haven't tried it yet on the cluster with the full parquet file, but that's my next step.

I used this as my example:
[Broadcast Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435263/dataframe-join-optimization-broadcast-hash-join)

Comment: I ran this on the cluster and was able to process a parquet input file of over 5mm without any memory issues.

Comment: We've recently executed this in a production testing environment.  When trying to run the full population of over 300mm, it fails with a driver memory error.  I will update the above code when we figure out a solution.

Comment: It's running in our production testing environment now, but the broadcast had to be removed because the key file was too large to broadcast.  As a result it shuffles to much to run locally, but runs great out on the cluster.