# How to update Spark dataframe based on Column from other dataframe with many entries in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am working with Spark dataframes and want to update a column `column_to_be_updated` in a hive-table using spark-sql in Scala.

My code so far does work with smaller dataframes:

```
var data_frame = spark.sql("Select ... From TableXX")

var id_list = spark.sql("Select Id From TableXY Where ...")..collect().map(_(0)).toList

data_frame.withColumn("column_to_be_updated", when($"other_column_of_frame".isin(id_list:_*), 1)
    .otherwise($"column_to_be_updated"))
```

What I want is to updated the column `column_to_be_updated` if the entry in  `other_column-of_frame` is in the id-column of `TableXY`. My workaround is to cast the id-column first to a list and then use the `.isin`-statement.

However, I have a lot of rows in `TableXY` and `TableXX` so it seems to crash and overload the `id_list`. Is there any other workaround or more efficient solution for what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the dataframes using an outer left join. In this way, the `Id` column can be added to `data_frame` on the rows where the `other_column_of_frame` is in the list of ids. Then, simply check whether the newly added `Id` column is null or not.

```
val ids = spark.sql("Select Id From TableXY Where ...")
val updated = data_frame
  .join(broadcast(ids), ids.col("Id") === data_frame.col("other_column_of_frame"), "left_outer")
  .withColumn("column_to_be_updated", when($"Id".isNotNull, 1).otherwise($"column_to_be_updated"))
  .drop("Id")
```

You can read about the `broadcast` here: [DataFrame join optimization - Broadcast Hash Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435263/dataframe-join-optimization-broadcast-hash-join)

Comment: I don't think this is what I want to achieve. I want to update a column to value `1` if the id is in the list as stated in my initial post.

Comment: @dnks23: You are correct, I updated the answer to take that into consideration.